# Cake Php paginator issue

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, paginator

I am facing a weired issue. I have written code for pagination. Everything is working as expected, but only conditions are not working(only certain conditions)
Here is my code for pagination.

```
//declaration 
public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 50,
        'paramType' => 'querystring'
    ); 
//use in action
$this->paginate['ApiLog'] = array('limit' => 50, 'order' => 'ApiLog.id DESC', 'paramType' => 'querystring');

$this->paginate['ApiLog']['conditions'] = array('ApiLog.log_type' => 2);
$this->paginate['ApiLog']['joins'] = array(               
            array(
                'table' => 'users',
                'alias' => 'User',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array('User.id = ApiLog.user_id')
            )                
        );
$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate['ApiLog'];
$apilogs = $this->Paginator->paginate('ApiLog');
```

This code is working prefect on development environment and return logs that has type 2, but in production it return only logs that has type 1. I have spent whole day to figure out issue. 
If i do add any other condition in `conditions array` that does take effect but not `log_type`. 
I print Query logs, in `where clause` it always show `log_type = '1'`
I have cleared cache as well. 
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try to delete your `tmp/cache` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed issue, This issue was due to `data type` declared into database. In production it was `tinyint(1)` and in development it given `int(1)`. It is saving correct value in database in both environment but in condition `tinyint(1)` is working with only 0 & 1 not with 2.

I didn't understand reason behind this.

Answer (score 2):

If your code working fine in local machine but not working in production then you have to clear all files in `tmp/cache/model` and `tmp/cahe/persistance`. make sure you have given writable permission to `tmp` folder.

It means you have to update Cake Model schema when you add new field, remove existing field or make any changes in database schema. In production mode If schema cache file not found then it will create new cache files based on current schema on database. In development mode on every execution it will update schema cache.

Still its issue in pagination then you have to follow CakePHP 2.x documentation. Here I assume your code is in `ApiLogsController` and method is `index`. as per documentation your code should be.

```
public function index() {
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'limit' => 50,
        'order' => 'ApiLog.id DESC'
        'paramType' => 'querystring',
        'conditions'=>  array('ApiLog.log_type' => 2),
        'recursive'=>-1, // should be used with joins
        'joins'=>array(
            array(
                'table'=>'users',
                'type'=>'LEFT',
                'alias'=>'User',
                'conditions'=>array('User.id = ApiLog.user_id')
            )
        )
    );
    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('ApiLog');
    $this->set(compact('data'));
}
```

OR

```
// your default setting in ApiLogController class
public $components = array('Paginator');
public $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 50,
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
);

public function index() {
// overriding/extending default settings

$this->Paginator->settings['order']='ApiLog.id DESC';
$this->Paginator->settings['conditions']=array('ApiLog.log_type' => 2),
$this->Paginator->settings['recursive']= -1;
$this->Paginator->settings['joins']=array(
        array(
            'table'=>'users',
            'type'=>'LEFT',
            'alias'=>'User',
            'conditions'=>array('User.id = ApiLog.user_id')
        )
    );

$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('ApiLog');
$this->set(compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: i have already cleared cache. Also my Paginator settings are correct. I do add any other condition in settings then it does work

Comment: Check in production with debug level 2 and display query  bottom of your layout.

Comment: There are four ways to show queries:

This will show the last query executed of user model:
debug($this->User->lastQuery());  
This will show all executed query of user model:
$log = $this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);       
debug($log);
This will show a log of all queries:
$db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db->showLog();
If you want to show all queries log all over the application you can use in view/element/filename.ctp.
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>

Comment: i have seen query and it always include `ApiLog`.`log_type` = '1' in where clause

Comment: which code you are using your or mine option 1 or option 2?